# PHP microtime() conversion to microseconds

Tags: php, floating-point, numbers, floating-point-precision, microtime

I want to get seconds and microseconds in one variable using the microtime(). If I do this:

```
$initial_time = microtime();
echo (explode(' ', $initial_time)[1]) . "\n";
echo (explode(' ', $initial_time)[0]) . "\n";
echo (explode(' ', $initial_time)[1]) + (explode(' ', $initial_time)[0]) . "\n";
```

I get:

```
1419714319
0.05059700
1419714319.0506
```

The last line is the same as if I would have called microtime(get_as_float) or microtime(true);

How would I get the complete result `1419714319.05059700` instead of `1419714319.0506`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of digits *displayed* in a floating point number is controlled by the [precision](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) setting in the PHP.ini file. Its default value is `14` and this is exactly the number of digits you see below:

```
1419714319.0506 // 10 digits before, 4 after decimal, 14 total
```

Change this setting to a larger number::

```
ini_set("precision", 20);
$t = microtime(true);
var_dump($t);
// float(1419716734.0712089539)
```

Note that this only controls the number of digits *displayed*, it does not affect calculations.

Having said all that, you can still use number formatting functions to display x number of digits after decimal:

```
$t1 = microtime(true);
echo sprintf("%.20f", $t1);           // 1419717225.92410898208618164062
echo number_format($t1, 20, ".", ""); // 1419717225.92410898208618164062
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets both and I hope this is what you needed.

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    echo (float)$sec.''.substr((float)$usec, 1);;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Exactly** as you specified, you probably can't (reliably, that is); the floating point value isn't necessarily representable.

The internal representation of the floating point will have all its decimals, but by default it's shown with a fixed number of digits.

The closest you can arrive is using `sprintf`:

```
$a =  1419714319.05059700;
print "$a\n";
print sprintf("%.8f\n", $a);
```

will output

```
1419714319.0506
1419714319.05059695
```

as you can see, there will be a small error. Of course another possibility is to separately store and handle the integer part and the decimal part, possibly pre-multiplying it by one million as a sort of scaling:

```
$not_a_float = implode('.', explode(' 0.', microtime()));
```

Note that `$not_a_float` does hold the "real" value of `microtime()`, but does so as a **string**. As soon as you perform any floating point operation on that value, *it will revert to the floating point precision* and the representation inaccuracy will creep back.

You can process separately the two parts; for time differences, you first calculate the difference between the integer parts, then add the second decimal part, then subtract the first:

```
((($after[0]-$before[0])+$after[1])-$before[1])
```

The parentheses guarantee to keep the [inaccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) to a minimum. Even so, be sure to keep all the processing possible after the timing, so that it doesn't affect timing itself:

```
$before_raw = microtime();
...
$after_raw = microtime();
$after = explode(' ', $after_raw);
$before = explode(' ', $before_raw);
$diff = ((($after[0]-$before[0])+$after[1])-$before[1]);
```